# How to Autowire a OkHttpClient bean in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I would like to `autowire` an instance of `OkHttpClient` in my Controller class. I have created a `OkHttpClientFactory` class and marked it as `Bean` in its constructor. I am including this as a `Autowired` in Controller class. However, I run into the following issue -

Bean -

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

@Configuration

public class OkHttpClientFactory {
    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient OkHttpClientFactory() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }


}
```

Controller -

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sap.lmc.beans.OkHttpClientFactory;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/recast")
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private OkHttpClientFactory client;

    private String url = "https://example.com/";

    @GetMapping(path="/fetchResponse", produces="application/json")
    public String getRecastReponse() {

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("conversation",response.body().string());
            return json.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage().toString();
        }   
    }

}
```

The following error results -

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method newCall(Request) is undefined for the type OkHttpClientFactory
```

Isn't the `Autowired` `OkHttpClientFactory` instance actually returning an object of `OkHttpClient` type. Then why is the method `newCall()` not applicable on it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this `@Autowired private OkHttpClientFactory client;` in your controller.

to

```
@Autowired private OkHttpClient client;
```

You want to @autowire to `OKHttpClient` and not the 'Factory' class.

Answer (score 3):

Your factory is a configuration class because you annotated it with `@Configuration` annotation. In your controller do not inject the configuration bean, but the bean that is configured inside it. This bean will be available in spring context and valid for `@Autowire`.

The class `OkHttpClientFactory` has no method `newCall(Request)` as you can obviously see.
You should change the field  `private OkHttpClientFactory client;` in your controller to `private OkHttpClient client;` and let spring inject the bean by type.